# Make Google search results link directly to linked page

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, firefox

Google search results usually link to google.com/url with a bunch of gibberish.

How can I make them link directly to the result?

I'd like a solution that works for both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: yes, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extension called "Don't track me Google".

[Download for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg?hl=en)

[Download for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dont-track-me-google1/)